# Integrar XML con Python para Vistas

Tags: python, xml, mvc

Voy a hacer un programa en python, y quisiera utilizar XML para crear las vistas del programa. 
Es decir, quisiera tener el código python en los archvos .py y las vistas en archivos .xml
Investigando un poco tendria que utilizar modelo-vista-controlador, mas quisiera saber si existe alguna otra forma.

Comment: ¿Y cómo planeas leer el XML y crear una interfaz a partir de él? ¿Vas a crear tu propio dialecto XML de especificación de interfaz? ¿Y sus correspondientes esquemas y validadores? ¿Y tu propio _framework_ de creación de GUIs? Creo que sería mucho más fácil si usas algo ya existente, como Qt. Este sistema es usable desde python (pyQt) y hasta tiene un diseñador "visual" de interfaces, que luego guarda como XML y que pueden cargarse desde programa (python), como [se explica en este blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/30/loading-ui-files-in-qt-for-python/) por ejemplo.

Comment: Chevere, pues usaré Qt.